# Creating not copyable, but movable, objects in c++

Tags: c++, boost, object, noncopyable, movable

Just a question. Looking at C++ Boost libraries (in particular boost::thread class) I ended up thinking: "how is it possible to create a class defining objects that cannot be copied but that can be returned from a function?"

Well consider this example, the boost::thread class has the characteristics I mentioned before, so it is possible to do this:

```
boost::thread make_thread();

void f()
{
    boost::thread some_thread=make_thread();
    some_thread.join();
}
```

Well this means that the object boost::thread cannot be copied, but returned from a function, this is possible.
How is this possible????

I suppose that a copy constructor must not be provided, but how to deal with returning from a function? doesn't it need to use a copy constructor???

Thankyou

Answer (score 6):

This is possible starting with C++11, which provides move semantics via rvalue references. Using this you can implement moving and/or copying separatedly:

```
class my_class {
  private:
    data_t* data_;
  public:
    my_class(const my_class& rhs)      // copy constructor
     : data_(rhs.data_.clone())
    {}
    my_class(my_class&& rhs)           // move constructor
     : data_(rhs.data_)
    {
      rhs.data_ = NULL;
    }
    ~my_class() {delete data_;}        // noop if data_==NULL

    my_class& operator=(my_class rhs)  // copy assignment
    {
      this->swap(rhs);
    }
    my_class& operator=(my_class&& rhs)// move assignment
    {
      this->swap(rhs);
    }

    // ...
};
```

Copying and moving can be forbidden separately, so you can setup classes that can be moved, but not copied.

Of course, there are a few magical tricks that let you do this even when your compiler doesn't yet support move semantics (`std::auto_ptr`, after all moves instead of copying when assigned to), so this might work for `boost::thread` even in the absence of move semantics.

Comment: What's c++1x?  I can see c1x and c++0x on the internet, but not c++1x.  Is it shorthand for both of them?

Comment: @Alex - it's smart-ass speak for the fact that it's already 2010 and they haven't released.  There's a smarter-ass counter: 0x is hexidecimal.

Comment: @Alex: It used to be named C++0x, because it was expected _before_ 2010, but this didn't work out. Many still stick to "C++0x", even though it will likely end up as C++11 or C++12.

Comment: @Noah: Then it would have to be C++0xX, though. `:)`

Comment: @sbi: not if x in `C++0x` is one of `[0-9A-F]`, or, hexadecimal. aargh, I have no sense of humor :P

Comment: @sbi: I think most committee members and compiler implementers still refer to it as C++0x, so I think it'd be more fair to say that it *is* named C++0x because it was expected before 2010. But that's just nitpicking. :)

Comment: @rubenvb: In C++, a hex number literal starts with `0x`, after that come the actual digits. `:)`

Comment: To really nitpick: it's *named* "ISO/IEC 14882: Programming Language C++ current draft", which at the moment is n3126 or something. For obvious reasons, it needs a nickname, which is most commonly C++0x, despite a lot of joking about C++1x when it became clear there would be no standard by the end of 2009.

Comment: @Steve: I wasn't revering to the "current draft", but the standard _as we will have it_ in 2011 or 2012, which would make it either "C++11" or "C++12". Since I didn't want to guess on the year, I replaced the last digit by an 'x'. `:)`

Comment: @sbi: Ah, right. In that case I correct my previous comment: its name will be "ISO/IEC 14882: Programming Language C++", the same as C++98 and C++03. Which can't possibly cause any confusion :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is an advanced topic of C++ if you want to do this in C++03. See [Howard Hinnants Unique_ptr C++03 emulation](http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/unique_ptr03.html) for an example of that.

It basically works by abusing several subtle rules in C++ overload resolution, in particular the rule that non-const references cannot bind to rvalue temporaries and that non-const conversion functions can still be called on non-const temporaries.

You can also use the auto_ptr technique as employed by C++03, which however is seen as broken by several groups because auto_ptr lets you copy variables, but steal resources from the copied-from object (other groups have other opinions about this).